# How to terminate only the child process?

Tags: c, fork

I want print an array of processes with their `pid` and `burst time`. For this, I generate the `pid` using `fork()` and then get it `pid` using `getpid()`. However, since fork creates a child process that runs in isolation from the parent process, I am not getting the expected behavior. What the program should do is generate process for given `number_of_process` and then store `pid` and random`burst time` value inside the specific structure element. Here is my code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

struct process{
    int pid;
    int bt;
};

int main()
{   
    int no_of_process,i,new_process;
    printf("Enter the number of process\n");
    scanf("%d",&no_of_process);
    struct process p[no_of_process];
    for(i=0;i<no_of_process;i++){
        new_process=fork();
        p[i].pid = getpid();
        p[i].bt = rand()%10;
        //kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<no_of_process;i++){
        printf("process %d and bt %d\n",p[i].pid,p[i].bt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to kill the child process but that stops the whole program.
The output for number of process = 2

```
process 6373 and bt 3
process 6373 and bt 6
process 6374 and bt 3                                                           
process 6376 and bt 6
process 6373 and bt 3
process 6375 and bt 6
process 6374 and bt 3
process 6374 and bt 6
```

Expected should have been just 2 processes with pid and bt(burst time).

> - How to kill the child process just after it stores pid and bt(burst time) or it cannot be done ?

Comment: Your child processes do the same thing as the parent processes, so you get behaviour you don't intend.  Test the value in `new_process` and do different things if it is zero (child) or not (parent).  Note that `getpid()` returns the current process's PID.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the same thing. Since memory is shared that's why that structure stores 5 elements for each process and then each process runs the loop 5 times. But how can I get such PID's without facing this issue and still having only the given no. of processes such that once process is created and I get its pid I can finish its execution. Is there any way to do that? In this case however I would have to figure out how to store the pid since both child and parent process are using different structures. is that possible?

Comment: @ZameerHaque memory isn't shared between processes - they are totally separate.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Thanks. That's what I was actually trying to say. So how would I have both processes share that same structure so that only 2 process are created and stored in the structure for no_of_process = 2.

Comment: @ZameerHaque you check the return value of `fork` as per the many answers below and in the parent process store the PIDs in the structure.

Comment: @ZameerHaque: What about the documentation of `fork` is not clear?

Comment: The function: `fork()` has three kinds of return values: ==0 means in child process.  >0 means in parent process  <0 means `fork()` failed.    The code needs to check for all three conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pay attention to the return value of [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). This small modification to your code probably does what you're looking for.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>

struct process{
    int pid;
    int bt;
};

int main()
{   
    int no_of_process,i,new_process;
    printf("Enter the number of process\n");
    scanf("%d",&no_of_process);
    struct process p[no_of_process];
    for(i=0;i<no_of_process;i++){
        new_process=fork();
        if (new_process == 0) {
            // This is a child process. Just spin until killed.
            while(true);
        }
        p[i].pid = new_process;
        p[i].bt = rand()%10;
        kill(new_process,SIGKILL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<no_of_process;i++){
        printf("process %d and bt %d\n",p[i].pid,p[i].bt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case the pid remains same for all the processes. Why ? I guess since the last process finished executing already ? How to generate a unique pid each time.

Comment: Running this exact code I get a different pid every time. Did you make sure to update the line from `p[i].pid = getpid();` to `p[i].pid = new_process;`?

Comment: Using a busy wait works, but calling `pause()` is often better.  It never returns normally; it only returns after a signal is handled (so with SIGKILL, it will never return), but it doesn't run and use any CPU resources while it is paused.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks. But why is it different that getpid(). getpid is supposed to give the current process id ? Oh. Since process already finished execution so I am using parents process id everytime I use getpid() ?

Comment: In this case the child process never calls `getpid();` only the parent process calls it, so it will return the same answer every time. The return value of `fork()` is how the child's pid is communicated to the parent.

Answer (score 7):

You aren't using `fork` correctly at all. When you call it, the child process continues executing the same code as the parent, but gets a different return value (0) to indicate that it is the child process. So in your code currently, the child processes are all spawning their own children.

The usual way use `fork` is to do something akin to

```
new_process=fork();
if(new_process==0)
  {
  // I am the child
  }
else if(new_process==-1)
  {
  // Something bad happened
  }
else
  {
  // I am the parent
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Tried the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077676/5143144, however the pid remains same now and does not change at all. The process should have unique pid.

Comment: the value of `new_process` will contain the unique PID for each child - you put that into your structure

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `new_process` is either 0 (so it's the child) or it's the pid of the child - no need to call `getpid` (ignoring -1 for failure)

so, in the parent (0 return value) call `fork` `no_of_processes` times